# Store duration of song in SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql, .net

I'm going to store the Length of songs in my table and I chose the data type as decimal(2,2), but I got error. I search for this question alot but couldnt solve it. Can any one tell me that which data type should I use and how exactly must write it in query?

[image]

Comment: @Igor: `TIME` is a time of day, *not* a duration. Aside from possible confusion with mapping data types on the client end, durations longer than 24 hours can't be represented this way -- though admittedly this isn't much of a limitation for songs in particular. SQL Server has no distinct type for durations, so a suitable numeric type should be picked depending on the application.

Comment: @JeroenMostert it really doesn't matter if it is a time of days to store and calculate it it is perfect to store song duration

Comment: @nbk: it happens to be *usable* for song durations. "Perfect" is a very big word, and getting into the habit of using `TIME` to store any kind of duration would be bad. On the T-SQL end, calculating anything duration-based with `TIME` is painful, for starters. The total length of a playlist could not be calculated with `SUM`, for example, you need to throw in all sorts of funky `DATEADD`/`DATEDIFF` contortions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your decimal specification is incorrect. `decimal(2,2)` says you have 2 numbers, 2 of which come after the decimal. Try `decimal(3,2)` and that should fix your error, but you might need to play with the precision and scale as you work further.

More information: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/decimal-and-numeric-transact-sql

> `decimal[ (p[ ,s] )]` and `numeric[ (p[ ,s] )]`

> p (precision)
> The maximum total number of decimal digits to be stored. This number includes both the left and the right sides of the decimal point. The precision must be a value from 1 through the maximum precision of 38. The default precision is 18.

> s (scale)
> The number of decimal digits that are stored to the right of the decimal point. This number is subtracted from p to determine the maximum number of digits to the left of the decimal point. Scale must be a value from 0 through p, and can only be specified if precision is specified. The default scale is 0 and so 0 <= s <= p. Maximum storage sizes vary, based on the precision.

Comment: Why are we using a decimal to store time? It's the wrong tool for the job...

Comment: There are certainly other ways of doing it, yes, but it's valuable sometimes to implement something yourself to understanding the shortcomings.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure decimal is the right way to store time, as the info after the decimal point isn't 100 based.

Could you store the duration as an integer? In seconds?

Writing:
3m:30s -> `3*60+30` = 210 seconds

Reading:
`210 seconds/60 + seconds%60` (3 + 30)

Comment: does it really matter which conversion you use, time as data type looks much better

Comment: @nbk that would work too I guess. Unless you have a song that exceeds 1 day in length ;)

Comment: that would not fit on a cd :D